# Arbitrary N-dimensional repeat of N-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Say you have the following ***N***-dimensional array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Z = np.array(7*[6*[5*[4*[3*[range(2)]]]]])
>>> Z.ndim
6
```

Note that ***N*** = 6, but I want to keep it arbitrary in the discussion.

---

Then I perform multiple-axis operations which -- of course subjectively -- ***problematically*** "collapse" (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521273/average-numpy-array-but-retain-shape) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523022/numpy-array-directional-mean-without-dimension-reduction)) dimensions along which those are computed.

Say that the axes of computation are

```
>>> axes = (0,2,5)
```

Thus the tuple's length belongs to [***1***,***N***].

---

As you might have guessed, I want to make the shape of the output of a, say, [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) be the same as that of its input. E.g.

```
>>> Y = np.mean(Z, axis=axes)
>>> Y.shape
(6L, 4L, 3L)
```

while

```
>>> Z.shape
(7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L)
```

---

I have a homemade solution, as follows

```
def nd_repeat(arr, der, axes):
    if not isinstance(axes, tuple):
        axes = (axes,)
    shape = list(arr.shape)
    for axis in axes:
        shape[axis] = 1
    return np.zeros_like(arr) + der.reshape(shape)
```

where incidentally `der` stands for "derived".

```
>>> nd_repeat(Z, Y, axes).shape
(7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L)
```

---

What is the ***numpy-builtin manner*** to accomplish this N-dimensional repeat?

---

Performance concerns, `import timeit`

```
homemade_s = """\
nd_repeat(Z, np.nanpercentile(Z, 99.9, axis=axes), axes)
"""
homemade_t = timeit.Timer(homemade_s, "from __main__ import nd_repeat,Z,axes,np").timeit(10000)

npbuiltin_s = """\
np.broadcast_to(np.nanpercentile(Z, 99.9, axis=axes, keepdims=True), Z.shape)
"""
npbuiltin_t = timeit.Timer(npbuiltin_s, "from __main__ import Z,axes,np").timeit(10000)
```

As can be expected

```
>>> np.log(homemade_t/npbuiltin_t)
0.024082885343423521
```

my solution is ~2.5% slower than hpaulj's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mean` has a `keepdims` parameter the retains the compressed dimension:

```
In [139]: shape=(2,3,4,5)
In [140]: x=np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
In [141]: m=x.mean(axis=2, keepdims=True)
In [142]: m.shape
Out[142]: (2, 3, 1, 5)
```

It's easy now to replicate `m` along that dimension:

```
In [144]: m1=np.broadcast_to(m,shape)
In [145]: m1.shape
Out[145]: (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

`repeat` and `tile` are also handy means of replicating an array along a dimension.

`broadcast_to` expands the array without adding elements, just by changing shape and strides:

```
In [146]: m1.strides
Out[146]: (120, 40, 0, 8)
```

`repeat` increases the size of the array:

```
In [148]: m2=np.repeat(m, shape[2], axis=2)
In [149]: m2.shape
Out[149]: (2, 3, 4, 5)
In [150]: m2.strides
Out[150]: (480, 160, 40, 8)
```

`m` could be used without either, as in `x-m`.  `m` broadcasts with `x` here.